# A list and a tokenized sentence separated by quotation `'` with space and without space in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset, and by regex I extracted the data. I used the `sent_tokenize` method of NLTK to define for me the sentence boundary.

```
tok = sent_tokenize(str(all_text))
print(tok[0])
It give me this output:


# List of string 
tok = ['Hi ' ,  hello at 'this ', there 'from ']
```

Now the annotated data that I have extracted from this dataset looks like:

```
i = ['there' , 'hello', 'Hi']
```

If you see, in the `tok list` the first quotation is with word and the closing quotation is with a space. But in the `i` list, an element of a list is closed with quotation without space. When I want to check if any element of `i` in `tok`, it should give me a result. but can not detect the text inside `tok`.

Comment: can you just do a `replace("'", "")` and `replace(" ", "")`? So replace the quote with an empty string and replace the space with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
tok = [j.strip() for j in tok]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. if you can see on `tok` list on some of the element we have the `quotation` not on all. those have quotation, they are member of the `i` list.

Comment: Oh, then use regex to grab everything between `quotation` for every element in the list and then do the thing that I suggested. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why `sent_tokenize` tokenizes each word in the sentence for you. but if you want tokens for each sentence, try something like this..

```
from nltk import PunktSentenceTokenizer, word_tokenize
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer()
tokens = [word_tokenize(i) for i in tokenizer.tokenize(all_text)]
```

Comment: Actually, the main problem is that the `tok` list is extracted the words inside tag in the dataset. If you can see those word which has a quotation with space on the right side is the word that I tag them.